# React Native pass useState Switch variable to other screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scope, global-variables, react-navigation

Beginner here. I'm struggling to pass my useState variable to another screen in my React Native project. The screen that contains the variable, "screenCheckboxes.js" is structured like

```
export default function screenCheckboxes({ navigation }) {

  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
  const toggleCheck = () => setCheck(previousState => !previousState);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Hello from Checkbox Screen</Text>

      <Switch
        onValueChange={toggleCheck}
        value={check}
      />

    </View>
  );
}
```

I want to render an image on another screen file, depending on if the checkbox switch is checked on or not. I figured I will be importing the checkbox screen using `import { check } from './screenCheckboxes.js';`

How would I go about using my "check" useState in another screen?

Answer (score 0):

pass it as a param while navigating to that screen or you can use something like redux or context api.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).